# For a real square matrix $A$ with all eigenvalues on the imaginary axis, does the following hold?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, normed-spaces, matrix-exponential

Given a real square matrix $A$ with all eigenvalues on the imaginary axis, does the following hold?

$\|e^{A}\|^2=\|Pe^{D}P^{-1}\|^2\leq\|e^{D}\|^2$ where $D$ is real Jordan form of $A=PDP^{-1}$. I know from http://www.math.wm.edu/~ckli/ima/note-3.pdf that, for unitary matrices $P$ and symmetric/anti-symmetric $D$, $\|e^{A}\|=\|e^{D}\|$. But not sure if the mentioned inequality holds when $D$ is the real Jordan normal form of $A$.

Comment: What norm is this?

Comment: Euclidean norm.

Comment: I mean, what matrix norm: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_norm

Comment: Spectral norm (2 norm, $\|A\|^2=\lambda_{max}(A^{T}A)$).

Comment: Spectral norm is invariant under conjugation, so isn't the inequality trivial?

Comment: First of all, thank for the response. But any formal proof or references to that? I do not see why $\|e^{A}\|=\|e^{D}\|$ under conjugation. Because in the mentioned problem $P$ is not a unitary matrix so $P^{*}=P^{-1}$ may not be true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a counter-example to show that this mentioned inequality may not hold in general. Let's take $A=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & -2\\0 & 1 & 0\end{bmatrix}$

which has eigenvalues $0,\pm{i\sqrt{2}}$. The transformation matrix

$P=\begin{bmatrix}0 & 0 & 1\\0.8165 & 0 & 0\\0 & -0.5773 & 0\end{bmatrix}$ and the real Jordan normal form

$D=\begin{bmatrix}0 & \sqrt{2} & 0\\-\sqrt{2} & 0 & 0\\0 & 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$.

$\|e^{A}\|=1.4084$ and $\|e^{D}\|=1$, so the inequality does not hold in general. Please correct me if I am wrong in this conclusion.

Comment: How do you get $\|e^D\|=1$?

Comment: I calculated $(e^{D^{T}}e^{D})$ which turned out to be an identity matrix.

Comment: I think since $A$ is not diagonalizable (not normal matrix i.e. $AA^{T}\neq{A^T}A$), the inequality may not hold. I can be wrong. I observed that $\|e^A\|^2=\|Pe^{D}P^{-1}\|^2\neq\|e^{D}\|^2=\lambda_{max}(e^{D^T}e^D)=\lambda_{max}(e^{(D+D^T)})$.                                                                      
                  Since $\lambda(e^{A^T}e^{A})\neq\lambda(e^{D^{T}+D})$ even though $\lambda(e^A)=\lambda(e^D)$.

Answer (score 1):

The eigenvalues of any matrix are invariant under conjugation. (Observe that $PMP^{-1}$ and $M$ satisfy the same minimal polynomial; it’s also easy to directly prove that an eigenvalue of one matrix is an eigenvalue of the other).

It follows that the spectral norm is invariant under conjugation,
$$\|M\| = \|PMP^{-1}\|,$$
regardless of the form of $M$.